# Access RecordSet is empty

Tags: vba, recordset

I got very simple Sub which is run by a Combobox in a Access Form. Combobox shows all values from a column from Products table. Based on that selection then other values should used to populate text boxes in this Form.
So basic data seeking case.

```
Private Sub ComboProductNameSearch_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strSearchCriteria As String
    Dim strSearchName As String

    Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
strSearchName = Me!ComboProductNameSearch.Value
strSearchCriteria = "Product name like '" & strSearchName & "'"

MsgBox (Me.Recordset.RecordCount)



rs.FindFirst strSearchCriteria
       If rs.NoMatch Then
           MsgBox "Record not found"
        Else
           Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
           MsgBox "Record is found"
        End If
```

User will now select a product and what happens is that Recordset is empty. Code always runs to Record not found due to that.
How can I access a correct Recordset ?
My form will use a query to find all data from that Table. Query works.
No linking to any other table or queries.

Watch :   : strSearchCriteria : "Product name like 'Vehicle, person car'" : String : Form_frmAddProduct.ComboProductNameSearch_AfterUpdate

Watch : + : ComboProductNameSearch : "Vehicle, person car" : Object/ComboBox : Form_frmAddProduct.ComboProductNameSearch_AfterUpdate

Watch :   : strSearchName : "Vehicle, person car" : String : Form_frmAddProduct.ComboProductNameSearch_AfterUpdate

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
strSearchCriteria = "[Product name] = '" & strSearchName & "'"
```

or, if the field name is *Product*:

```
strSearchCriteria = "Product = '" & strSearchName & "'"
```

Also, normally the *RecordsetClone* is used:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSearchCriteria As String
Dim strSearchName As String

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
```

If the form displays records, so will RecordsetClone.

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks for your kind support. That I have tried no help because the RecordSet is empty. MsgBox (Me.Recordset.RecordCount) gives 0. There is nothing to search against. I have been thinking this a lot  today but I still do not get it. What is wrong, how to get RecordSet filled up ?!

Comment: Make sure, the form has some records. If not, its Recordset is empty.

Comment: Interesting, what does it mean that form has records ? It has empty textboxes and in form  properties I have set Record Source to point to this specific table. My comboxos shows correctly all products from Products-table. Recordset type is default Dynaset. For is fine to have whole table as it is but somehow setting Recordset to point to table was not accepted, this is error (object required): Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(“Products”)

Comment: Try using `RecordsetClone`. See expanded answer, please.

Comment: Tested like this, and no records found just  EOF 
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
   
    Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
 
   If rs.EOF Then
      MsgBox ("EOF no records")
   Else
      rs.MoveLast
      MsgBox ("Records found")
      rs.MoveFirst
   End If

MsgBox (Me.Recordset.RecordCount)

Comment: Then, as suggested, use `RecordsetClone`.

Comment: Gustav, thanks I wasn´t noticed there is both Recordset.Clone and RecordsetClone. However not working. See my additional post.

Comment: You have set _Data Entry_ to _Yes_. Then the form will only display new records you enter, thus - at load - zero records.

Comment: Okay, will try that when back to office. What is good practise to both fetch data and also allow writing data, it cannot be anythign special. Do I turn that attribute to Yes / No depending on operation I am doing ? (in VBA)

Comment: Set it to: _No_

Comment: That worked right away. A big thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

[Property Sheet of the Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbBmq.jpg)

In my Form RecordSource is that very same table.

```
Private Sub ComboProductNameSearch_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    'Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    

   If rs.EOF Then
      MsgBox ("EOF no records")
   Else
      rs.MoveLast
      MsgBox ("Records found")
      rs.MoveFirst
   End If

MsgBox (Me.Recordset.RecordCount)
```

Still no fire no smoke
EOF and 0 records.